# Removing all nodes from a queue of structures

Tags: c, structure, free

I'm trying to delete all nodes from my queue of structures.

Structure:

```
struct element{

    int id;
    int sign;
    int year;
    int month;
    double amount;

    struct element *next;
};

struct queue{
    struct element *head;  

    int size;
};
```

And the function I wrote:

```
void delete(struct queue *queue) {
    if (queue->size == 0){
        printf("Structure is empty\n");
    }
    else {
        struct element* this;
        struct element* other;      

        for(this=queue->head;this!=NULL;this=other)
        {
            other=this->next;
            free(this);
        }
        free(queue);
    }   
}
```

It doesn't work, and I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: One thing I can see is that the info about how many elements you have is redundant. You have `size` in queue, but also a NULL pointer for `next` in the last element in the queue. Have you made certain that those always match? I mean, if you traverse the list, is it guaranteed that you can run `size` elements before you hit NULL?

Comment: @MrLister When I try to use this function Netbeans breaks it (Signal received: SIGABRT (Aborted)). No specifics

Comment: But in which line does it abort? Can you debug the program and/or insert some diagnostics printf statements?

Comment: Yes, I don't think that's an issue, when I had in the loop `for(i=0;i<size;i++)` it didn't work either.

Comment: How do you call `delete`? I suspect, queue is not allocated on the heap.

Comment: @Henrik Im `main` I have a previously implemented and filled queue (declared as `struct queue new`. I call delete as `delete(&new)`

Comment: Ah, if you don't `malloc` the queue, you should not `free` it! See Henrik's answer.

Comment: By the way, stupid question, and completely off topic, but why do you have identifier and function names like `this`, `delete` and `new`? Just curious.

Comment: @MrLister I do malloc it, when I fill it with data. And my original names of identifiers are different, I just translated it into English so it would be easier for the readers.

Comment: Oh... you just said that you just created a variable of type `queue`. If you are using a variable of type `queue*`, you should show the code where you `malloc` it and fill it then. That might be where it goes wrong.

Comment: Adding: `void add(struct queue *queue, int y,// etc){struct element *n= (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element)); n->year=y; etc  n->next=NULL;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `delete` routine, you do not free the `queue` if the size is empty, but you do free it if the size is non-empty. You should probably do the same for both cases. That is, either don't free in both places, or free in both places.

It is bothersome to need to figure out what the right thing to do is, because `delete` can not know how the `queue` was allocated. Given your current design, a way out may be to pass a flag to `delete` to indicate what it should do:

```
void delete(struct queue *queue, int do_free) {
    if (queue->size == 0){
        printf("Structure is empty\n");
    }
    else {
        struct element* this;
        struct element* other;
        for(this=queue->head;this!=NULL;this=other) {
            other=this->next;
            free(this);
        }
        queue->head = 0;
        queue->size = 0;
    }
    if (do_free) free(queue);
}

struct queue new;
/* ... */
delete(&new, 0);      /* don't free the queue */

struct queue *empty_new = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
empty_new->size = 0;
delete(empty_new, 1); /* free the empty queue */
```

Comment: Why should I free it if it's empty (assuming I understood your point)?

Comment: @ozech: I'll answer with a question: Why do you free it after you empty it out?

Comment: To wipe it out from the stack completely

Comment: @ozech: You can only `free` memory that was returned by `malloc` or `calloc` or `realloc`. An empty queue on the stack is taking up just as much memory as an emptied out queue on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
struct queue new;
//...
delete(&new);
```

`new` is allocated on the stack, so don't call `free(queue)` in `delete`.
Instead, set `queue->head = NULL; queue->size = 0;` to indicate that the queue is now empty as mentioned by @kirill.

Comment: I should call `free(&queue)` instead?

Comment: @ozech - no, if it's allocated on the stack as in the code in my answer, it will be freed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

How about just passing the first element of the queue.

```
void delete(element *el ) {
    if(el) {
        delete(el->next );
        free(el);
    }
}
```

with

```
typedef struct _element{

  int id;
  int sign;
  int year;
  int month;
  double amount;

  struct _element *next;

} element;
```

Answer (score 0):

you might have forgotten to update at the end of the function the pointer to NULL as well as changing the size of the queue to 0.